# Is it possible to delete an element from a random position in a queue implemented in C?

Tags: c, queue

I came across the following question and spent hours trying to figure out why there is a `x` in the remove function (I'm talking about question '(v)')

I see no reason for having a `x` because removing an element from the queue happens from the front and we already have the address of the front node stored (as a member in the `struct`).

It would be great if someone could please help me clear out this doubt because I tried to do so on my own but couldn't.

[image]

The next part of the question is as follows which is even more confusing...

[image]

Comment: that's depends on implementation you can go through the entire queue and searches for match and delete it

Comment: They are asking you to remove an arbitrary element, not the front one. That said, this is a badly written question because `QueueElement` was not defined. And also because they defined a `Boolean` enum where `TRUE==0` and `FALSE==1` which is completely backwards and will easily lead to mistakes.

Comment: I wouldn't lose any sleep over this; its a really bad question.  `x` could be the element to be removed, and it being null meaning remove the front element; it *could* mean anything, or nothing at all.  Specifying that is the responsibility of the author of the question.

Comment: If it is possible to remove a random element from the queue, why is it called a queue after all? Why not create a linked-list instead?

Comment: It's also possible that they want you to remove the front element and store its value into `*x`. The question isn't clear but SO can't help you, you'll have to ask whoever assigned it.

Comment: @jkbliss from the spec it looks as if the queue is implemented as a singly linked list

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes it is a singly linked list implementation of a queue.

Comment: @jkbliss interjay's comment  is certainly correct. Most likely `Insert` is supposed to add an element at the rear of the queue, and `Remove` is supposed to remove an element from the front.

Comment: Throw that source away.  The question is not just badly worded, the code is downright horrible.  Take a close look at the indentation in the `while(i != 0)` loop...

Comment: @AndrewHenle yeah that may be done with the intention of confusing the candidate... probably

Comment: As @jkbliss comments, the only correct answer is 'No, because such an operation is not supported by a queue':(

Answer (score 1):

The question is worded unclearly, but the `main` function you posted makes it clear what the code is supposed to do:

1. `QueueElement` seems to be a typedef to `int`, which is the value type stored in the queue.
2. `Remove` is supposed to remove the front element of the queue, and store its value into `*x`.

This is the case because in `main` it calls `Remove(&i, &numqueue)` and then prints the value of `i`.

As as aside, this code is badly written and hopefully you won't pick up too many bad habits from it. In particular, defining a `Boolean` where `TRUE==0` and `FALSE==1` is backwards and can lead to mistakes where `if (bool_value)` does the opposite of what it appears. This mistake actually happens in `main` where they wrote `while (!QueueEmpty(...))`.

Comment: If that's the case why is `&i` passed to the remove function? Is there any use in doing so?

Comment: Also, why store it in `x` as you say? The `struct` definition has a variable called `front` which is to be used for this purpose isn't it?

Comment: @jkbliss It's passed to the function in order to receive the value of the element that was removed. They could have made the function return the value instead (which you would call with `i = Remove(&queue);`), but they chose this method.

Comment: @jkbliss You don't want to store it in the struct. You want to *remove* it (so it will no longer be stored in the queue), and `*x` is used to tell the caller what value was removed.